# Making a scrollable List without drop down lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a transition page that stands as a break between the Login page & the main page.

The Page contains nothing but The list of names  ... So, I don't want to make it to be a drop down list ... I want the page to be filled with a scrollable list.

I tried making a div with some buttons inside it, but it doesn't look good. So, do you have any ideas on how can I make the page looks better, or whether I should use 2 divs inside each other & modify them using CSS?

This is what I made: 
JS:

```
function GetClassesList(data) {
var classes = (typeof data) == 'string' ? eval('(' + data + ')') : data;
$('#ClasssesList').empty();
for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    var text = '<button class="BigDiv" value="' + classes[i].Cls_ID + '" >' + classes[i].Cls_Name + '</button>';
    $('#ClasssesList').append(text);
}
$("#ClasssesList").bind('click', 'button.BigDiv',CallLink()); 
}
```

HTML:

> ```
>        <div id="ClasssesList" ></div>
> ```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your code works fine... If I understand correctly, you could define the height and width of #ClassesList and set the overflow to scroll in the CSS. Then, you can format the buttons to appear however you wanted when you are formatting the html inside of the for loop.

I don't understand exactly what you are looking for though. Maybe if you could clarify a bit.